# Editing XML but prevent changing XML structure?

Tags: xml, editing

Is it at all possible to prevent users from changing the XML structure in a file, but only enter/modify data?

There is nothing in [XSD Restrictions/Facets](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp) that specifies this.

I have seen [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063784/512728) about specifying read only nodes, but:

1. I want the opposite: node contents should be editable editable, node structure not.
2. Do I have to code something myself, or *if this is possible* do XML editors support this?

I don't want to make this a software request, but I have no idea what direction I have to take to accomplish this?

Note: This is in a 'controlled' environment, i.e. colleagues have to enter the data, but I don't want them to *accidentally* change the structure.

Comment: no not with any common editor. also consider that attribute values are data, but I'm guessing you are considering them structure. using an editor that checks for a well-formed document, and perhaps validates against a very strict XSD on save is a start, but it still won;t stop a user from deleting half your rows, or whatever. you would still have a well-formed, valid document, but it would be missing data. You will want to write a data entry interface that uses the xml document as its data-source. some platforms and frameworks make that a breeze. and you can't stop notepad...

Answer (score 0):

`xmlstarlet` has a [command](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch03s02.html)
which describes an XML document as a list of XPath expressions:
element names and optionally attribute names and values, ignoring
element and optionally attribute contents. So compare the output from
this command, after piping it through `md5sum`, before and after
editing the XML document to decide whether edits are acceptable.

If `xmlstarlet` is not available it's not complicated to produce a
similar output using an XSLT processor.